# Debian server only accept LC_* variables, not LANG, via SSH

Tags: debian, ssh, locale

My local `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` has

```
SendEnv LANG LC_*
```

The server-side `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` has

```
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
```

Nevertheless, when I SSH to my Debian server, I noticed that `$LC_*` family is passed to the server side, but `$LANG` didn’t go through; the server still uses `en_US.UTF-8` there. How can I make it respect my client-side `$LANG`?

In case it matters, I’m using Debian 11 (Bullseye).

Answer (score 2):

This might be Debian-specific. One need to run `dpkg-reconfigure locales`, and choose *None* as the default locale (I previously set `en_US.UTF-8` there). From [Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/Locale#Standard):

> If you chose a default locale other than *None* above, it will be in `/etc/default/locale` and will override the `LANG` variable supplied by ssh.

(I consider it misleading to call it “default” locale, because it overrides your explicit choice, instead of acting like a fall-back choice. More like “enforced locale”.)